# How can i check user id in login section?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I use Google sign in button with google package.
If user choose sign in with google, and if user login first time, then i want to create his/her account, but my code create when she/he login to app, everytime create like new user. I want to check with if statement, but how i do not know. If user uid exist in firestore, then it have not to be create new account.

This is my google sign in login function:

```
Future login() async {
    isSigningIn = true;

    final user = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    if (user == null) {
      isSigningIn = false;
      return;
    } else {
      final googleAuth = await user.authentication;

      final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );

      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').add({
        'email': user.email,
        'username': user.displayName,
        'uid': user.id,
        'userPhotoUrl': user.photoUrl
      });

      isSigningIn = false;
    }
  }
```

Firestore console image here

[image: Firestore console here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem with my friend which is good person.
I replace this code :

```
 await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
```

because there is a logical problem.

Comment: i shared , look at the above

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store per-user information in Firestore, you should use the user's UID as the ID of the document.  It's guaranteed to be unique per user.  Don't use `add()` to add the document with a random ID, use `set()` with the known ID to read and create the document.

Also, you should know that [signInWithCredential](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/signInWithCredential.html) returns the known user object, which lets you get their UID.

```
UserCredential userCrediental = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
String uid = userCredential.user.uid;
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid).set(...)
```

If you want to check if the document was already created for that user, you can simply try to `get()` it first and see if it exists.

Comment: if (existingUserDocs.docs.isEmpty) {
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').add({
          'email': user.email,
          'username': user.displayName,
          'uid': user.id,
          'userPhotoUrl': user.photoUrl
        });
      } else {
        return null;
      }

i use this code. but it gives an error which is permission.
here, error: 

FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.)

Comment: also i use allow read, write: if request.auth != null;  this code in my firestore, although this, it gives an error

Comment: That sounds like a different problem, which you should post as a new question.